# Returning a value from popup window using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to create a popup page from a parent page, which will return a value to the parent page and will close eventually.

What I have done so far:

main.php:

```
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<td><input type="text" name="project_name" id="pid" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="button" name="choice" onClick="selectValue('id')" value="?"></td>
</tr>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectValue(pid){
    // open popup window and pass field id
    window.open('search_project.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(pid),'popuppage',
  'width=400,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=400,top=100,left=100');
}

function updateValue(pid, value){
    // this gets called from the popup window and updates the field with a new value
    document.getElementById(pid).value = value;
}

</script>
</head>
```

search_project.php:

```
<head>
<script>
function closeWin(){
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendValue(value)
{
var parentId = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['id']); ?>;
window.opener.updateValue(parentId, value);
window.close();
}
</script>


<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT project_id from prjct where project_id like 'default'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Select" onClick="sendValue('<?php echo $sql['project_id']; ?>')" /></td>
<td align="center"><? echo $sql['project_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

So, it is supposed to close the popup(search_project.php) and return the value of project_id in the input field of main.php. But, nothing is happening when I'm clicking on the select button. The popup doesn't close and the value is not returned. Seems sendValue(value) is not working.

Need help.

Comment: your passing two parameters to `window.opener.updateValue(parentId, value);` but its only setup to accept one.

Comment: @DevZer0, I wrongly wrote `function selectValue(pid)`, its actually:
`function updateValue(pid, value)`

Comment: make sure you access the page via `http://` not `file://`

Comment: I am working on a server. So, I am using `http://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want encodeURIComponent(pid) here?

Try without encodeURIComponent:

```
    window.open('search_project.php?id=pid','popuppage',
       'width=400,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=400,top=100,left=100');
```