# Retrieving a value from innerHTML or textContent using JQuery map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

Using information I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897154/returning-a-value-from-popup-window-using-php-and-javascript) question I have been able to retrieve my driver information, and combining it with rowIndex place it in the correct cell.

```
reservations.rows[whichRow].cells[7].innerHTML = which_driver;
reservations.rows[whichRow].cells[7].textContent = which_driver;
```

I've tried both and the proper data shows.

Now using information I found in another question (I can't find it) I have been using this function to retrieve the values as I loop through the selected rows (checkbox)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
        var values = $("#main_table table input[name=name]:checked").map(function() {
                row = $(this).closest("tr");
                return { 
                         recordid    : $(row).find('input[name=record_id]').val(),
                         firstname   : $(row).find('input[name=firstname]').val(),
                         lastname    : $(row).find('input[name=lastname]').val(),
                         timeneeded  : $(row).find('input[name=timeneeded]').val(),
                         dateneeded  : $(row).find('input[name=dateneeded]').val(),       
                         pickup      : $(row).find('input[name=pickup]').val(),       
                         dropoff     : $(row).find('input[name=dropoff]').val(),       
                         drivername  : $(row).find('textContent[name=driver_name]').val()
                        }
            }).get();
        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

When I view the objects in the console all the other fields show the correct, but driver name is 'undefined'.

Is there a way to grab that information or a way to put the data from the popup into the "value" of the proper cell.  So far, I haven't been able to get that data to show.

Thank you

Here's the actual  from the HTML -

```
"<td id="driverlist" width='125' align='left' onClick="selectValue('id',this)" value="?" > <input type="text" id="driver_name" name='driver_name' "size='15' style='font-weight: 700' value=''"> </td>"
```

When the user clicks in the field it fires a function that returns the rowIndex and then fires the Popup, once a person is selected then it returns the value and fills in the proper cell –

I modified the map function to read

```
drivername : $(row).find('textContent[name=driver_name]').text()
```

and now it at least returns "" and not undefined. –

Comment: `textContent` is an HTML DOM property, not a DOM element.  You need to use a selector in `find` that selects the cell, and then use `text()` to get the value.  It's difficult to help much more without seeing your html.

Comment: Edit your post with updates to code for clarification; don't post them as comments.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use

```
: $(row).find('td:eq(7)').text()
```